# x86 Assembly: Why Do I Need Stack Frames?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

On most x86 Assembly (NASM especifically) code samples I see around (even on the ones generated by GCC) I see what's called "setup of stack frame". Like this:

```
main: 
        /*setting the stack frame*/
        push    ebp     
        mov     ebp,esp

        ...
        code goes here
        ...

        /*removing the stack frame*/
        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp
```

I have 3 questions about this practice:

1. If my code doesn't touch the stack then setting/removing the stack frame as above is completely useless, right?
2. Even if my code uses the stack, as long as pop everything I push (leaving the stack as it was essentially) then again setting up a stack frame is completely useless, right?
3. As I see it the only purpose of this would be to save the value of ESP so that I can play around with it on my code without worrying about messing things up, and once I am done I simply restore its original value. Is this the purpose of the stack frame setup or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: The stack frame is also necessary if you want to debug your program and see the stack trace.

Comment: stack frame is not really need. As you can see. In the X86-64, we don't have stack frame and the ebp register. So you are right, stack frame just used for convenient.

Comment: `-fomit-frame-pointer` is on by default in Linux `gcc -m32`, when optimization is enabled.  That might not have been the case in 2013, or if you were using an even older compiler, but it's been the case for years now (in 2018).  `-fomit-frame-pointer` has always been on by default in x86-64 mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, in fact, you don't need stack frames.

Stack frames are convenient when you save registers and store local variables in stack - to make writing and debugging easier: you just set `ebp` to a fixed point in stack and address all stack data using `ebp`. And it's easier to restores `esp` at the end.

Also, debuggers often expect stack frames to be present, otherwise you can get inaccurate stack call for example.

So, the answer to 1 is yes, the answer to 2 and 3 is above.

Answer (score 4):

You are essentially correct.

Stack frames do have certain benefits, though, even when you don't need a fixed stack reference to access parameters and locals. In particular having them there allows for accurate stack walking for generating stack traces for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

This is done by convention. C language functions use stack frames to access parameters that are sent to functions, and to set up dynamic local variables. That is why they do it in the sample code that you are looking at. Of course if you want to do it your way, you can, but you won't be able to invoke your code from C etc.

EDIT: I am also pretty sure that there are compilers that implement different calling conventions that optimize that and maybe do not create a frame at all. So basically, you are right. Stack frames are not necessary.

Comment: parameters are actually at negative offsets from the base of the current stack frame.

Comment: It uses stack for passing parameters to functions, but if I remember it correctly it doesn't specify using stack frames. In fact, function calling convention doesn't depend on stack frames at all.

Comment: @akonsu It seemed to me that your wording implied that, but my mistake.

Comment: the code inside a function in C uses stack frame base (I am not sure what the right term is) to access the parameters and to set up local variables. The parameters are outside the frame base (negative offsets) and the locals are inside the frame. That is how I remember this from 20 years ago. :)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen thanks. I have changed the wording. assembly was much fun to use. long time passed since. I am not using it anymore...